# Sonar: Members of Spring components should be injected

Tags: java, spring, sonarqube

in the current project we are using Sonar for code checking and there is a rule Members of Spring components should be injected (https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-3749/) So let's say I have a service class with a field which is not neither injected nor static:

`@Service public class myService { private  MyObject myObject; ... }`

If I declare it as static or if I add initialization by null in constructor (i.e. this.myObject == null) it is ok for Sonar and the rule is not trigged. For the 1 option, if my class is singleton, modificator static should not change anything, is not it? For the second option, in Java objects are initialised as null by default, are not they? Could you please comment? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If they aren't injected, what are they then? If this is for keeping state then don't do it, else you should be injecting it.

Comment: yes, they are keeping a state, and yes, this is not a good practice. But in my project I see that sometimes they are set to null in the constructor and Sonar is ok with this solution. And I do not understand why is he ok

Comment: Keeping state is indeed not a good practice and in concurrent situations will lead to errors, simply don't do this.